# SAPUI5: Add properties to Column added via View Settings

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I want to add `width` and `mergeDuplicates` properties to a column inserted via the View Settings dialog.

Is there a standard SAP way of doing this or do I need a add custom javascript?

Comment: what do you mean by "add via View Setting dialog"? the column should already be specified in the xml view, the visibility of columns can be configured with the "TablePersoController"

Comment: The brief was not to define the column in the xml view but thankfully they have just changed their mind. Thanks for the tip about `TablePersoController`

Comment: also if you want to change properties dynamically just bind them in a 2 way json model, if you change the model the properties will change too. Just do the tutorial on sapui5.hana.ondemand.com

Comment: @Erch Which tutorial covers that? Thanks

Comment: Data Binding ... But you might just want to do them all